# Can I remove .subscribe() from map by using another RxJS operator?

Tags: rxjs

Is there an alternative to doing .subscribe() in map?

```
return this.http.patch<any>(URL, { test: true }).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.nextSomething$.next({})),
    filter(_ => this.filter),
    map(resp => {
      this.someObservable({ message: 'do' }).subscribe()
      return resp
    })
)
```

I tried doing switchMap and returning the previous response but my observable does not complete.

```
switchMap(prevResp => 
  this.someObservable({ message: 'do' }) }).pipe(map( _ => prevResp))
)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your observable is not completing when you switch to using the flattening operator then that means the target observable in that operator isn't completing.  So you might want to check what's going on in **someObservable** that causes it to never complete.  It is likey that behavior isn't desirable.

If you know that **someObservable** will emit at least once, then you can add the **first** operator to the inner *pipe* method:

```
switchMap(prevResp => 
  this.someObservable({ message: 'do' }) }).pipe(
    first(),
    map( _ => prevResp)
  )
)
```

If you don't care what **someObservable** does - you don't want to wait for it just want it to execute, then wrap the observable in **firstValueFrom**.  It converts an observable into a promise that emits the first result.  This code smells, but it should do the trick.

```
this.http.patch<any>(URL, { test: true }).pipe(
  tap(() => this.nextSomething$.next({})),
  filter(() => this.filter),
  tap(() => firstValueFrom(this.someObservable({ message: 'do' })))
)
```

Maybe, you don't care to wait for this observable to emit, but you're still looking for an orderly execution of **someObservable**.  In that case you can use a subject that emits every time you want it called, and use **concatMap** to ensure the execution is performed in an orderly fashion.

```
private readonly someObservableRequest = new Subject<string>();

constructor() {
  this.someObservableRequest.pipe(
    concatMap((message) => this.someObservable({ message }))
  ).subscribe(); // be kind, please unsubscribe
}

someMethod() {
  return this.http.patch<any>(URL, { test: true }).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.nextSomething$.next({})),
    filter(_ => this.filter),
    tap(() => this.someObservableRequest('do'))
  );
}
```

Comment: Went with tap(() => firstValueFrom(this.someObservable({ message: 'do' })))
but I believe mergeMap(todo => this.someObservable(...).pipe(mapTo(resp)))
does the same

Comment: I used to do the random firing off of observables from observables, but as apps grew I realized it was quite advantageous to try to coalesce everything into as few streams as possible with the objective of having one state in a class.   It makes things much more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your point right, you have to execute consecutively 2 Observables.

In this case you need yo use one so called "higher order" operators, i.e. either `concatMap` or `switchMap` (there are other "higher order" operators but I feel they do not apply to your case).

The code then would look like this

```
myNewOservable this.http.patch<any>(URL, { test: true }).pipe(
    tap(_ => this.nextSomething$.next({})),
    filter(_ => this.filter),
    // an higher order operator returns an Observable
    concatMap(resp => {
      return this.someObservable({ message: 'do' })
    })
)
return myNewOservable
```

Now you can `subscribe` to `myNewOservable`.

In my example I have used `concatMap` which ensures that a value notified by the upstream Observable is processed through the downstream pipeline before processing the next value from upstream.
I could have used also `switchMap`, which has a slightly different behavior: as soon as a new value is notified by the upstream Observable, any downstream processing is terminated.
In this case, given that `http` emits only one value and then `complete`s the 2 operators act the same.